# correct minor mistakes in my php and mysql code

Tags: php, database

Problem:
i have problem when inserting values of dept_no into emp table. Values cannot be inserted while in dept table dept_no is successfully inserted

- Emp (emp_no,emp_name,address,phone,salary,dept_no)
- Dept (dept_no,dept_name,location)
- Dept-Emp  are related with one-many relationship. Create a relational database for the above and perform the following:

Using above database write PHP scripts which will:

1. Insert employee records & department records into the respective tables.
2. Print a salary statement in the formatlocation given below, for a given department. (Accept department name from the user).

My code..

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //first name of employee
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //to collect errors in an array
    $errors = array();
    //employee's id
    if(empty($_POST['emp_no'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter employee number!";
    }else{
    $emp_no = trim($_POST['emp_no']);
    }
    //department number
    if(empty($_POST['dep_no'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter employee number!";
    }else{
    $dep_no = trim($_POST['dep_no']);
    }
    //department name
    if(empty($_POST['dep_name'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter department name!";
    }else{
    $dep_name = trim($_POST['dep_name']);
    }
    //department location
    if(empty($_POST['dep_location'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter department location!";
    }else{
    $dep_location = trim($_POST['dep_location']);
    }
    //employee's first name
    if(empty($_POST['first_name'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter first name!";
    }else{
    $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
    }
    //employees last name
    if(empty($_POST['last_name'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter last name!";
    }else{
    $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
    }
    //employees address
    if(empty($_POST['address'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter address!";
    }else{
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    }
    //employees phone
    if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter phone number!";
    }else{
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    }
    //employees salary
    if(empty($_POST['salary'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter phone number!";
    }else{
    $salary = trim($_POST['salary']);
    }
    //check if no errors
    if(empty($errors)){
    require('dep_emp.php');
    }

    }
?>

<form action="emp_print.php" method="POST">
<p>Employee Form</p>
<p>Employee Number <input type="number" name="emp_no" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['emp_no']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Department Number <input type="number" name="dep_no" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['dep_no']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Department Name <input type="text" name="dep_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['dep_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Department Location <input type="text" name="dep_location" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['dep_location']; ?>"/></p>
<p>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Last Name <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['last_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Address <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['address']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Phone Number <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['phone']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Salary <input type="number" name="salary" value="<?php    if(isset($_POST['submit']))echo $_POST['salary']; ?>"/></p>    
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert"/></p>

</form>
```

dep_emp.php

```
<?php

//connect to the database
$dbc = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','black98765','activity_7a')
       OR die("Could not connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());

//insert values into department table
$q2 = "INSERT INTO dept (dept_no,dept_name,location)
VALUES ($dep_no,'$dep_name','$dep_location')";
//insert values to employee table
$q = "INSERT INTO emp      (emp_no,dept_no,first_name,last_name,address,phone,salary)
VALUES ($emp_no,$dep_no,
'$first_name','$last_name','$address','$phone',$salary)";       
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
$r2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$q2);
if($r && $r2){
echo "<p>Successfully Inserted!</p>";
}else{
echo "<p>System Error!</p>
<p>Data are not been inserted!</p>";
echo "<p>".mysqli_error($dbc)."</p>";
}
mysqli_close($dbc); 
?>
```

Comment: Please help me out with this activity iam having hard time isolating problems thanks

Comment: Your conditional statements are missing **{}**

Comment: Thanks for replying i got this error.System Error!

Data are not been inserted!

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`activity_7a`.`emp`, CONSTRAINT `emp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `dept` (`dept_no`))

Answer (score 0):

why use the select statement here?

```
'SELECT dept_no FROM dept where dept_no = $dep_no'
```

Aren't you just selecting the exact same value you just inserted into the department table?  Why not just

```
VALUES ($emp_no,$dep_no,'$first_name'...
```

I'm new to php, so I could easily be wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$q2 = "INSERT INTO dept (dept_no,dept_name,location)
VALUES ('$dep_no','$dep_name','$dep_location')";

$q= "INSERT INTO emp SET emp_no='$emp_no',dept_no='$dep_no',first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',address='$address',phone='$phone',salary='$salary'"
```

Comment: yeah its working now but when i enter the same dep_no the output will be System Error! Data are not been inserted!. since this is one to many relationship i want to use the same dep_no.how can i get rid of that message..thanks

Comment: same dept no means i cant understand

Comment: the dept table has dep_no column as its primary key also the emp table has emp_no as its primary key and dep_no from the dept table as its foreign key..

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is working but theres still a problem the first time i enter all the values in the form the message will say Successfully inserted see the dep_emp.php above- but when i insert the same value to dept_no different names salary ,etc..in the form the message now change to system error!Data not inserted. But the values name,salary are being inserted to the emp table ...I want now to get rid of these message.How to do that thanks

Comment: i think you set unique for dept_no  in your mysql table .check your table and remove unique attripute

Comment: Im very sorry but how can i unset dept_no  as unque when this column is set as primary key?

Comment: Then the data in dept table will duplicate. And we don't want that to happen.Are there any solutions you can suggest?Thanks for the continous responses..